# Does my attached drawing accurately depict amperage measurement

Tags: measurement, amperage

I want to measure the amperage in my system without destroying anything. Is my drawing an accurate representation of where the probes should be placed?
[image]

Comment: This will only measure the current through the left motor

Comment: It depends on the current waveform and your meter. This could work but, it may not be accurate depending on waveform and meter type.

Comment: why 3 wires to the switch? otherwise it looks good.

Comment: The motor runs very hot. It was suggested the amperage through the motor be measured.

I have to correct my drawing. It is missing a fourth wire to the switch.

Comment: Are you sure it's a brushed motor?

Comment: Yes. When I got it, the spindle was hard to rotate by hand. I took it apart and it has four  brushes.

Comment: If the spindle is stiff, that could be why it is getting hot. The motor should stay cool if it is spinning freely and not doing any significant work. Have you put a scope on the output of the controller, to check that it is steady DC and not pulse-width modulated or something strange?

Comment: When I took it apart the bearings rotated very smoothly so I thought they were OK. Initially I ran it with a 19V 3.4A wall wart and it only got slightly warm after running about 20 minutes. I got a Mean well power supply and a PWM DC motor controller. With those components it got very hot after 20 minutes. The power supply and controller checked out OK. The last check will be the current flow. If that checks out OK the problem is likely  bearing misalignment.

Comment: Some months back I was told DC brushed motors do not spin freely by hand. It that true?